# ffmpeg expression operator "or" not work

Tags: ffmpeg

ref:https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation

[image]

ffmpeg expression or (+) not work.

```
if((gt(t,10))+(lt(t,30)),0,1)
```

the result is always 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working as expected.

`gt(t,10)` is `1` for all times greater than 10 i.e. `10.01,11,12.....infinity`

`lt(t,30)` is `1` for all times lesser than 30 i.e. `-inf...28,29,29.99`

So the expression `gt(t,10)+lt(t,30)` is true for all values of `t`.

If you want it to be true for values (10,30) only, use `*`. Or you could just use `not(between(t,10,30))`

Comment: thank you very much! if i want to implement if  elseif ,  is this work?
 if(expr1,val1,if(expr2,val2, val3))

Comment: Yes, that's a form of if-elsif-else